# Creating a usable comma-seperated INT list variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to create a query that declares a variable that stores a comma-separated int list then re-uses that list in a WHERE statement later on. The parameters will have to be passed in the format IN (int,int,int) etc... and will always change dependent on value of @TG. Below is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @TG int = 14168

DECLARE @TG_ITEMS varchar =  (SELECT  
                             STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  
                                ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10),  i.item_key, 120)
                                    FROM store__tracking_group sitg
                                    JOIN store_tracking_group_detail sit 
                                    JOIN item i 
                                    WHERE sitg.number IN (@TG)  
                                    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''))




--- MAIN QUERY HERE

SELECT ''
FROM ''
WHERE 'xx' IN (@TG_ITEMS)
```

Comment: Assuming SQL server, guessing by the syntax - this won't work without dynamic SQL, or a function which splits that string into a table somehow. Why can't you create a temporary table/table variable which holds your list of IDs, and then join to that in your other queries? If you're on version 2008+, the preferable way of doing this is a table valued parameter.

Comment: Just create a temp table with the ids you want. Then join on the table. No need to convert to a string.

Comment: The `IN` operator expects a list of values separated by commas, while you try to give it a single value containing comma-delimited data. That's the difference between `IN(1,2,3,4)` and `IN('1,2,3,4')` - the first one will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong approach.  SQL databases have a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*, not a character string.

One way to do what you want in spirit is a table variable:

```
DECLARE @TG int = 14168;

DECLARE @TG_ITEMS TABLE (item_key int);

INSERT INTO @TG_ITEMS(item_key)
    SELECT DISTINCT i.item_key
    FROM store__tracking_group sitg JOIN
         store_tracking_group_detail sit 
         ON ??? JOIN
         item i 
         ON ???
    WHERE sitg.number = @TG; 

SELECT ''
FROM ''
WHERE 'xx' IN (SELECT item_key FROM @TG_ITEMS);
```

This has many benefits, such as readability and performance.